# find everything to the left of (multiple input)

Tags: excel

**My files**

Workbook 1 containing Laptops and Inventory sheets, inventory will grab data from laptops taking only the laptop names.

**Objective**

Extract product names (10,000 entries) from the sheet Laptops e.g. Compaq CQ58-250SA

**Plan**

We only need the product names so find certain keywords (computer specifications) and take everything to its left (name of the product)

**Keywords to target**

- Celeron
- Pentium
- B815
- E1-1200
- B820

**Spreadsheet Data**

- Cell A1 = Compaq CQ58-250SA Celeron B830, Windows
- Cell A2 = HP 650 Pentium B980, 15.6 HD AG LED SVA,
- Cell A3 = Asus X401A-WX321H, B815, Windows 8
- Cell A4 = Compaq CQ58-256SA E1-1200, Windows 8 64
- Cell A5 = ASUS, X401A-WX089V, B820, Windows 7

**What I have done so far:**

=LEFT(Laptops!A1,FIND("Celeron",Laptops!A1)-1)

**What I need to do**

=LEFT(Laptops!A1,FIND("Celeron"&"Pentium"&"B815,Laptops!A1)-1)

Comment: I'm not following... what exactly are you trying to do?  What does your inputs look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on updated question you could use this formula assuming only one keyword per cell and list of keywords in D1:D5

`=LEFT(Laptops!A1,LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(D$1:D$5,Laptops!A1))-1)`

Otherwise if there might be more than one keyword per cell......

Which version of Excel are you using? In **Excel 2010** you could utilise **AGGREGATE** function like this

`=LEFT(A1,AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND(D$1:D$3,A1),1)-1)`

where D1:D3 is your "fruit list" - expand as required

[15 in AGGREGATE function indicates "SMALL" function and 6 ignores errors, so you get the smallest value from FIND(D$1:D$3,A1), while ignoring errors - thus giving you the position of the first fruit in the cell]

This can be entered as a regular formula and copied down, if none of the fruits are found it gives an error but you can use IFERROR function to modify that to return a text value or the whole contents of A1

Note: **FIND** is "case-sensitive" - use **SEARCH** instead if you don't want that

In **Excel 2007** or later you can use **IFERROR** and therefore this "array-entered" version

`=LEFT(A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND(D$1:D$3,A1),""))-1)`

Comment: Extremly Interesting however I am getting a #Value when it cannot find the keyword

Comment: @Ninja2k With which formula? Which version of Excel are you using? If no keywords are found what result do you want?

Comment: Excel 2010, was thinking just blank using the "" should do it right?

Comment: In Excel 2010 you can wrap the formula in IFERROR, e.g. for the LOOKUP version `=IFERROR(LEFT(Laptops!A1,LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(D$1:D$5,Laptops!A1))-1),"")`

Answer (score 5):

If your list of fruits is in `D1:D3` you could use this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(INDEX(D1:D3,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&D1:D3&"*"),0)),A1)-1)
```

It needs to be entered as an array formula, by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Comment: + 1 Superb! Short and Sweet :)

Comment: If A1 can contain multiple fruit then this formula wouldn't necessarily give you all text to the left of the first fruit - depending on the order of fruits in D1:D3, e.g. if D1 = "Apple", D2 = "Pear", D3 = "Orange" & A1 = `"two trees, Pear and Apple"` then formula returns all text to the left of Apple (rather than to the left of Pear). My suggested formulas should always return the text to the left of the first fruit - if there will only ever be one fruit per cell then you can use this non-array formula `=LEFT(A1,LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(D$1:D$3,A1))-1)`

Comment: **Ctrl-Shift-Enter** I suppose for the Array formula?

Comment: @barryhoudini this is for Doug: "It needs to be entered as an array formula, by pressing **Ctrl-Alt-Enter**." in the answer. Edited it, sorry for the confusion)

Comment: @Peter L. OK, sorry I see now

Comment: @barryhoudini, I've admired your use of Lookup with this kind of formula before, and committed to using it. I seem to have failed (although I have a sense of when I would use it). I like it because it's non-array. I like the Index/Match type formula because I already use those so much I can follow the logic easily, which is nice with super-formulas. I am going to try to remember the Aggregate function for sure though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace any instances of Pear and Orange to Apple, and then use this (should be all on one line, but broken up for readability):

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("Apple",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Pear","Apple"),"Orange","Apple"))
    -1)
```

Now, if there are no instances of Pear, Apple or Orange, you'll get `#Value`, so let's handle that too by using `ISERROR` to check for an invalid value:

```
=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(A1, FIND("Apple",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "Pear", "Apple"),
    "Orange", "Apple"))-1)),A1,LEFT(A1, FIND("Apple", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, 
    "Pear", "Apple"),"Orange", "Apple"))-1))
```

Comment: Ok this works but my example was just a simple version of what I need :O can I Pm you little Bobby for help so I can avoid a duplicate question?

Comment: @Ninja2k - it's probably best to update your question with your exact situation so we can best help you.

Answer (score -1):

My version is a little shorter. Also needs to be entered as an Array Formula:

```
=MAX(1-ISERR(SEARCH(D1:D3,A1)))
```

Returns 1 if found, or 0 if not found. Work it from there.

Comment: I think you're being picky. I've done the difficult bit. The OP can do the easy bit depending on how his worksheet is configured. If that's not good enough  for you, I apologise.